# Git-All and Runit Problems in 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, git, runit

When I am trying to install the git-all from the repositories `sudo apt-get install git-all` at the end of the installation process I get some errors:

```
    start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

It seems that the runit package is not configured yet, the system is a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install. Does anyone know how I should configured it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing git-daemon-sysvinit before git-all:

```
sudo apt-get install git-daemon-sysvinit
```

git-daemon-sysvinit is an alternative for git-daemon-run, and it works better on Ubuntu 15.04 and up. (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164)